# AngularJS editable-text change height (also of button)

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I will change height of input form (and also the buttons - save and cancel).
Here is an example but I could not change the height of the input form:

[My try](http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/10356/)

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="$form.$cancel()" type="button">
```

I would be thankful for help.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You suggest that you want to change the **height** of your input, yet the CSS (which you didn't post in the question body) only has **width** values defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didnt specify the height with Elements
Css need to be changed:

```
div[ng-app] { margin: 50px; }
.editable-has-buttons.editable-input { width: 200px; height:100px; text}
.editable-input.btn-sm {width: 10px;}
.editable-controls.form-group{
    height:200px;
}
```

Fiddle for solution:http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/10362/

Comment: Would it be possible to also set the height and weight of the two buttons to  20px? I couldn't do it :-( Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have a look on updated Fiddle . and upvote and validate the answer if it would help you anyway